# Is this proof of divergence of an alternating series correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r-1}(\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r})$ is convergent, absolutely convergent, or divergent.

The way the textbook did it is that they let $b_r = \sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r})$. They proved that $\sum_{r=1}^\infty b_r$ is divergent and **concluded** that  $\sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r-1}(\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r})$ is divergent too. If the details of the proof matter, I attach it below:

[image]

I believe this is wrong because they get rid of the $(-1)^{r-1}$ part and proved that only $b_r$ is divergent. I don't think this is enough to say that the whole series is divergent. For example, $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r}$ diverges but the "alternating version" of it $\sum_{r=1}^\infty ((-1)^{r-1} *\,\frac{1}{r})$ converges.

Is the textbook proof valid or not? If not, how can I prove this correctly?

Comment: The proof that the series with all terms positive diverges is correct, so the original series (with alternating signs) is not absolutely convergent. But that does not prove it is not convergent. Indeed it you look at $b_n-b_{n+1}$ that is some constant times $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, so I would expect the series to converge.

Answer (score 3):

Noting that

$$\begin{align}
b_r&=\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r}}
\end{align}$$

it is easy to see that $b_{r+1}\le b_r$ and $\lim_{r\to \infty}b_r=0$.  That is, $b_r$ monotonically decreases to $0$.

Therefore, the [Leibniz's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) for convergence of alternating series guarantees that the alternating series $S$ given by

$$S= \sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r-1}b_r$$

converges.